# javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image

Tags: java

after getting the byte array when I am passing the byte array inside `BufferedImage` using `BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);`

It is showing the error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data at   
com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source) at  
com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source) at  
javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source) at
javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

what might be the reason behind this?

Comment: whats the value of `in` when you do `BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);`?

Comment: There should be a wrapped exception in your output with more helpful information than "Error".